# Store data from BroadcastChannel.onmessage in a variable

Tags: javascript, scope, message, web-worker

I need to fetch data from a dedicated worker, and store it inside other threads.

I'm trying to do it using the BroacastChannel API,but while I managed to get the data and console.log it in other threads, I can't store it in a variable.

I tried something like

```
var x = ""
channel.onmessage = function(event)=>{x = event.data}
```

but while the x gets redefined inside the brackets, the x in the outer scope stays unchanged. (I purposefully tried var instead of let, to see if I could circumvent the scoping).

All of the examples I found either use the response to console.log, or store it in local storage or into an html element. Neither of these options are good for me: I need the data in a variable.

Comment: How and, most importantly, *when* do you check the value held by that variable? After the MessageEvent fires, your `x` variable should hold the value that was passed in it as `.data`.

Comment: You're right, it was a timing problem. My checks were based on a wrong timed model too so they didn't help. Thanks